# react js date format with moment

Tags: javascript, reactjs, date, momentjs, date-parsing

```js
var start_date = ["2020-05-07 18:30:00"];
var header_date_array =  ["2020-05-07 12:59:12 PM", "2020-05-07 14:29:12 PM", "2020-05-07 18:30:00 PM", "2020-05-07 20:29:12 
PM"];


//match or compare date with same format 
//what i should i do?

//this is my logic, but it is not working
 const isSameDate = (start_date, header_date) => {
   const startDate = moment(start_date);
   const headerDate = moment(header_date_array);

   return startDate.isSame(headerDate, 'day');
 }
console.log(isSameDate);
```

I have facing an issue in React js. I want to compare/match the two dates `start_end` or `header_date` and shows on render component page.

My code example:

```
  {this.state.appointmentdata.map(data => 
      { const dateTime = moment(data.start_date.toString()); //start_date
        const headerDate = moment(this.state.headerdatearray);    //header_date
        return headerDate.isSame(dateTime, 'day');
    })
  }
```

```
console.log data (Date Format )
```

```
start_date: 2020-05-07 02:15:00     //format: "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss"

header_date array: ["11:57:16 AM", "11:27:16 AM"]
```

But the date formats are different. How can I get same date with same format?

Comment: did not get you.. both are moment objects so you dont need to worry about which format they are getting logged.. or is ur que diff ? you can use `moment` methods to compare the dates..

Comment: Can you `.format()` both to get them to a standard format? They both are Moment objects though, so formatting is rather irrelevant.

Comment: yes i try  `.format()` [@drew-reese](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8690857/drew-reese)

Comment: yes `moment`? is this right logic for compare two dates [@panther](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1009750/panther)

Comment: you have any better approach? how i can compare two dates  [@panther](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1009750/panther)

Comment: TBH is still isn't clear what the issue is. Can you provide a more complete example, and possible a running codesandbox that repros your issue? Your "Date Format" bit, is `["11:57:16 AM", "11:27:16 AM"]` the `headerDate` format/shape before or after passing it to Moment?

Comment: The header also is an array of two times, but no date, you can't compare to any specific date.

Comment: It still isn't clear what you are trying to accomplish. Based on updated question it now seems you want to check if *a* date, i.e. `start_date`, shares the same day as *some* date in an array. Is this correct?

Comment: None of the elements in the `header_date_array` have a "date" associated with the time, so they can *never* have the same "day".

Comment: i updated the `header_date_array` one date is match to `start_date` [@Drew](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8690857/drew-reese)

Answer (score 0):

The header dates are an array, so you likely want to iterate over it, constructing a luxon `DateTime` object for each, and check if it has the same `second` as the specified start date. Checking `seconds` unit includes *all* larger units, i.e. same minute, hour, day, week, etc... As long as *some* header date has the same then return true.

*Edit: I couldn't get formatting to work as expected using `momenjs`, and since you sounded open to alternative suggestions, IMO `luxon` is a better utility for handling DateTime objects (it's made by the same organization, btw)*

```
const isSameDate = (start_date, header_date_array) => {
  const startDate = DateTime.fromFormat(start_date, 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss');
  return header_date_array.some(header_date => {
    const headerDate = DateTime.fromFormat(header_date, 'yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss a');
    return startDate.hasSame(headerDate, "second");
  });
};
```

Given header date array and appointment data:

```
const header_date_array = [
  "2020-05-07 12:59:12 PM",
  "2020-05-07 14:29:12 PM",
  "2020-05-07 18:30:00 PM",
  "2020-05-07 20:29:12 PM"
];

const appointmentData = [
  {
    start_date: "2020-05-07 18:30:00"
  },
  {
    start_date: "2020-05-07 09:30:00"
  },
  {
    start_date: "2020-05-08 18:30:00"
  },
  {
    start_date: "2020-05-08 09:30:00"
  }
];
```

Map as such

```
appointmentData.map(({ start_date }) =>
  isSameDate(start_date, header_date_array)
)
```

> `[true, false, false, false]`

[image: Edit heuristic-cookies-n8xx4]

Comment: i implement your code they just match `day` how i can match `day with time` in moment [@drew](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8690857/drew-reese)

Comment: `startDate.isSame(headerDate, "daytime");` like this? [@drew](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8690857/drew-reese)

Comment: @MHasan You can simply specify a smaller unit, i.e. `second`, and it will also check all larger units (minute, hour, day, etc..). I had issues parsing them into valid moment objects so instead converted over to luxon. Updated answer.

Comment: how can i import `luxon`  ? any package installed [@Drew](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8690857/drew-reese)

Comment: it is not working proper `luxon`  [@Drew](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8690857/drew-reese)

Comment: @MHasan Did you check out the codesandbox I linked? Luxon is a package, `import { DateTime } from "luxon";` is how it's imported.

Comment: yes i do [@Drew](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8690857/drew-reese)

Answer (score -1):

As per your current code structure, I tried out as below:

```
var start_date = ["2020-05-07 18:30:00"];
var header_date_array =  ["2020-05-07 12:59:12 PM", "2020-05-07 14:29:12 PM", "2020-05-07 18:30:00 PM", "2020-05-07 20:29:12 
PM"];
```

If start_date is array,

```
this.start_date.map(start_date => {
  this.isSameDate(start_date, this.header_date_array);
  console.log(this.isSameDate(start_date, this.header_date_array));
})

const isSameDate = (start_date, header_date) => {
  const startDate = [moment.utc(start_date).format('L'), moment.utc(start_date).format('LTS')].join(' '); // You can replace LTS with LT to eliminate seconds.
  let flag;
  header_date.map(d => {
    d = d.substring(0, d.indexOf("PM")); // if I don't remove "PM", then moment says invalid Date. I have not dug in-depth to find reason.
    const headerDate = [moment.utc(d).format('L'), moment.utc(d).format('LTS')].join(' '); //Again here You can replace LTS with LT to eliminate seconds.
    startDate == headerDate ? flag = headerDate : flag = 'no appointment logged';
  })
  return flag; // you can use 'start_date' in order to return date instead.
}
```

Comment: it is hard to understand your code [@Shoma](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7901403/shoma)

Comment: can share any example code `codesandbox` (@Shoma)[https://stackoverflow.com/users/7901403/shoma]

Comment: Are you comparing "11:57:16 AM" with "11:27:16 AM"?

Comment: no comparing with `start_date: 2020-05-07 02:15:00` to each `header date: ["11:57:16 AM", "11:27:16 AM"]`  they check in an array if `start_date` exist or not [@Shoma](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7901403/shoma)

Comment: I have edited my answer, see if you can understand, let timeDiff = m1.diff(m2); can return you if date is different of not. In this way you can modify for your self. Also one thing seems missing, i.e. the date in the array, where it will consider as todays date time, what you say?

Comment: i updated a snippet code above , you check it  [@Shoma](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7901403/shoma)

Comment: Thanks, much clear now. I have change my answer as per requirement. Let me know if it works as per your current code structure.

Answer (score -1):

**There can be multiple options for this:**

***Run This command in the terminal:***

```
npm install moment --save
```

***Usage in React js Component:***

```
import Moment from 'moment';

render(){
    Moment.locale('en');
    var dt = '2020-05-07T02:15:00';
    return(<View> {Moment(dt).format('d MMM')} </View>)
}
```

You may check the moment.js official docs here https://momentjs.com/docs/

***Or you can use this package***

```
npm install date-fns --save
```

***Usage in Code:***

```
import { format } from "date-fns";

var date = new Date("2020-05-07 02:15:00");

var formattedDate = format(date, "MMMM Do, YYYY H:mma");

console.log(formattedDate);
```